# Javascript how can I call an element of an object if the object is inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I have a bunch of objects inside of an array, and I was wondering if it was possible to call on a certain variable within this object by using an array index?

Eg.

```
function myObject(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

var myArray[];

for (i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
  myArray.push(new myObject(10, 15));
}

//Now i want to fetch the x value of the fourth object in this array
var x4;
x4 = myArray[3.x];
```

This code would not work, but I'm wondering if there is something like this that would work?

Comment: It's `myArray[3].x`

Comment: You can use by `myArray[3].x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x4 = myArray[3.x];` is close but you need to move your property "x" outside the array item selection "myArray[3]".

`myArray[3].x`;

Comment: Glad it worked, don't forget to mark your question as answered